# How to disable animation when selecting a kendo-ui tab using select(tab)

Tags: jquery, animation, tabs, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo-ui tab strip in my application and I have disabled all animations related to that the configuration as follows.

```
$("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation: false
});
```

This is working fine when I'm opening tabs, no animations at all. But the problem comes when I'm opening a tab through code using select method as following.

```
var tabStrip = $("#tabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
tabStrip.select(tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li").eq(1));
```

It is showing an animation when opening the tab, as I guess it is the default animation of tab strip. I want to disable that as well. If you have an idea about how to do it, please answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `select`, use the `activateTab` like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div>Content 1</div>
    <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
<a class="activate" href="#">Activate Tab 2</a>
```

CSS:

```
.activate {
    margin-top: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

JS:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabstrip");

$tabs.kendoTabStrip({
    animation: false
});

$(".activate").on("click", function () {
    $tabs.data("kendoTabStrip")
        .activateTab($tabs.find(">ul>li:eq(1)"));

    return false;
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GaHaG/3/

Docs here: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#methods-activateTab

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct and clear answer. But in my case this was not the case. It is working fine with select() also. The fault was in my code is I've used a different method to get the tab item to select, which I've not shown above to simplify the code. In my real application it was like

```
var getTabItem=function(target, index){
    var tabStrip = $(target).kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
    return tabStrip.tabGroup.children("li").eq(index)
}
```

So I was calling this method within the select method to get the tab item to be selected. In that method I was using **kendoTabStrip()** to get the tab strip, as I think it is re-initializing the tab strip and drop the **animation: false** setting which I was done initially. I removed that part as I have already initialized the tab strip and then It started to behave as expected. Anyway your answer is a correct answer and this is totally my fault. Thanks for the help and I think this post will be helpful for others who are facing this kind of issues.